# Uncaught TypeError: obj[key].includes is not a function inside a filter

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I'm having a problem when I try to filter an array searching for a specific value

[image]

This array that I filter, I always looking for a specific "CodigoPostagem", so what I do is:

```
return rootState.emailsOpen
                .filter(obj => Object.keys(obj)
                  .some(key => obj[key]
                    .includes(email.CodigoPostagem)));
```

The "rootState.emaislOpen" is the object, inside of it there is a lot of objects that contains those data like the image "0: Object..."

The includes try to search for a specific number of CodigoPostagem, like 32, 31, etc.

What I need is that it return the entire object (0: Object) or at least the position.

---

rootState JSON:

```
{
   "pending":{
      "emails":false,
      "messageOpen":false
   },
   "error":{
      "emails":null,
      "messageOpen":null
   },
   "emails":[
      {
         "CodigoPostagem":32,
         "DataMensagem":"2017-07-02T13:32:00",
         "Emitente":"INOVA Farma",
         "Titulo":"Item,
         "Visualizado":true
      },
      {
         "CodigoPostagem":14,
         "DataMensagem":"2017-06-28T14:35:00",
         "Emitente":"INOVA Farma",
         "Titulo":"Mensagem número 14",
         "Visualizado":true
      },
   ],
   "messageOpen":null,
   "emailsOpen":[
      {
         "CodigoPostagem":14,
         "DataMensagem":"2017-06-28T14:35:00",
         "Emitente":"INOVA Farma",
         "Titulo":"Mensagem número 14",
         "Mensagem":"Test",
         "Visualizado":true
      },
   ],
   "wait":true,
   "loaded":true,
}
```

Comment: The error is telling you that for some `key`, `obj[key]` is a value of some type that does not have a `.includes()` method available.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to close the `.some()` method?

Comment: I think I don't need to use this `obj[key]` because when I debug it's already inside the object, so I tried something like it but nothing returns too:
`.filter(obj => Object.keys(obj).some(obj.CodigoPostagem === email.CodigoPostagem));`
or
`.filter(obj => Object.keys(obj).CodigoPostagem === email.CodigoPostagem);`

Comment: @MarceloFormentão Please post the `rootState` and `email` values as JSON so that we can see what your data really looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.filter()` already search in each object inside, so what I needed to do was include only the object with the parameter I need to compare, like this:

```
return rootState.emailsOpen
                .filter(obj => obj.CodigoPostagem === email.CodigoPostagem);
```